# How to improve initialization (start up) time for AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The time for an EC2 to launch an intialize seems to have come down in the past 9 years (at least they are now much faster than [10 minutes](https://serverfault.com/questions/179714/fastest-time-to-get-an-ec2-instance-running). But it can still easily take a few minutes. Are there any ways to reduce the amount of time that the instance status is "Initializing"?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I guess that time is moving the OS image to the VM so it can be started, but that's a guess. Initializing isn't even an [official state](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html).

Comment: The modern *5 class machines boot faster than their previous counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across a benchmark a few months ago that indicated a possible trend between the size of the root volume and the initialization time.

I'm trying to find that article again now myself so I don't have a link for you I'm sorry.